# Issues downloading MySQL as a CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download

I am having trouble outputting a mysql database into a csv file and downloading it. The bellow code produces the error `"unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"` on the 3rd line bellow. I have tried it with semicolons and without on the 3rd and 4th lines.

```
$FileName = "/googleresearch" .  abs(rand(0,1000000000000))  .  ".csv";

$query = "SELECT * FROM happyturtle INTO OUTFILE $FileName;
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

exit;
```

Comment: Basing your output filename on a random number isn't entirely reliable. The probability is low, but if there's a conflict, MySQL will *NOT* overwrite a file that already exists. Instead, you should base the filename on the current timestamp, which you can get as a regular integer with `time()` in PHP. Of course, if you run this query more than once a second, you'll still have the overwrite problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your `"` on the fourth line like:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';
```